# A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'ConnectionString'

Tags: sql, powershell

I am trying to connect to a database using a connection string and run a .sql script.

While trying to run:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ConnectionString $CString -InputFile .\deleteOldData.sql
```

I got this error:

`A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'ConnectionString'`

The [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps) has -ConnectionString listed as a part of Invoke-Sqlcmd so I'm confused why the command is not working.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the right module? That same cmdlet is in [another](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlps/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps) module, and that version does not have `-ConnectionString` as a parameter.

Answer (score 4):

The module `SQLPS` has an `Invoke-Sqlcmd` which does not have a `-ConnectionString` parameter. There is also an `Invoke-Sqlcmd` in the `SqlServer` module.

```
Install-Module -Name SqlServer
```

See this [documention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/powershell/download-sql-server-ps-module?view=sql-server-ver15) for more details.

> SQLPS: The SQLPS module is included with the SQL Server installation
>   (for backward compatibility), but is no longer being updated. The most
>   up-to-date PowerShell module is the SqlServer module.